# Vue cant recognize src

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I created a project using @vue/cli@4.5.11 (Babel, TS< Router, Vuex, CSS Pre-processors, Linter/formatter)

When I do

> npm run serve

it says

> These dependencies were not found:
>
> - src/config/GlobalConfig in ./src/store/user.ts

I am importing it like so:

```
import { GlobalAxios } from 'src/config/GlobalConfig';
```

and when I change it to /src/config/GlobalConfig

i get the following type error:

```
Cannot find module '/src/config/GlobalConfig' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

What should I do to properly use the file in the store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a relative path (and maybe the file extension depending the project configuration)

Maybe:

```
import { GlobalAxios } from '../config/GlobalConfig'
```

Or:

```
import { GlobalAxios } from '../config/GlobalConfig.js' // .ts ?
```

Or (if webpack alias is configured):

```
import { GlobalAxios } from '@/config/GlobalConfig.js' // .ts ?
```